# DialogFlow: import training phrases from a document rather than input manually?

Tags: dialogflow-es, training-data

DialogFlow: how to import training phrases from a document rather than input manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a lot, you could use API to add them programmably. What you need is to add your training phrases to Intent through https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents

Another one-off and hacky is to export the agent in agent settings, edit the exported files (look for the user says files), add your training phrases there, and restore.